# Cloud Firestore associate logged user with collection

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to know the best approach/pattern to implement for the following use case.

I'm using **Firebase Auth** to sign up/in users and it's working fine. 
As soon as the auth is performed I need to fetch from a **Cloud Firestore** collection, say `user_profile`, the data related to the logged user.

The problem is that the collection has its `id` which is not related to the user, since it's automatically generated by Firestore. So I don't know what to put in `<user>`

```
db.collection("user_profile").doc(<user>).get()
```

A possible solution I came up with is to store the user `id` inside `user_profile` and then query the whole collection like this

```
 db.collection("user_profile").where("id", "==", id_from_auth).get()
```

Making the `id` field index of the collection.

Is this a good approach? 
Is there a `better/smarter/automatic` way of doing this?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the uid of the authenticated user as the unique key of the document in your user collection?

Comment: mm that's something I didn't think of, but it could be a good solution. If you mind making an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Did you find a way that works? Im struggling to find a way to get the uid from the authentication tool (which is the docId of the user collection) to let me access that user collection. If you can share how you managed to access these attributes, I'd be grateful. The firestore documentation does not work for me - the Firebase team response to this enquiry is that it does not support usage in react (which is a javascript framework).

Comment: Hi @Mel, I'm doing as I explained in the question. I'm storing the AuthID as attribute of the User collection and then perform a simple query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's customary to store per-user data in a document keyed by the uid of the user authenticated by Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson. I have a question as i am using default login byFirebase, and i am not having any user collection in my firestore. How can I bind logged in user to it firestoredata??